# I am using sql server to send email from stored procedure with excel attachment. it is sending email with attachment but not in incorrect excel format

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

1. I am using SQL server stored procedure to send an email with an excel attachment. This procedure is sending email with attachment but not in correct excel format.
2. the attachment file does not display properly, it is disturbed columns and rows. Please help me to fix the file and make it display as a valid excel file.

   ```
   DECLARE @qry VARCHAR(8000);
            DECLARE @column1name VARCHAR(50);
            SET @Column1Name = '[sep=,' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'id]';
            set @qry = 'set nocount on;select id ' + @column1name + ' ,* from #tt';
            exec(@qry)`


   EXEC msdb.dbo.Sp_send_dbmail     
                 @profile_name = 'mydatabase',  
                 @query='exec mydatabase.dbo.[Getreport]',
                 @execute_query_database = 'mydatabase',
                 @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,                   
                 @query_result_no_padding=1,
                 @body_format = 'html',     
                 @recipients =  'getreport@gmail.com',     
                 @subject = 'Notification ',     
                 @body ='<h2>Hello</h2>',  
                 @query_attachment_filename = 'result.xls',
                 @importance = 'HIGH';    

            SELECT 'success';
   ```

Comment: Does this help? [send email with excel attachment using sql stored procedure](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/send-email-with-excel-attachment-using-sql-stored-procedure).

Comment: i have solved my 50% issue by adding this query @query_result_separator=' ', now it coming in good excel format but column heading is still not bold. i want excel column to be bold.so Please help me for proper excel column heading.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't generate results in Excel's native XLS / XLSX formats, rather it can generate them as a basic delimited text file, for example as a CSV (or include the results inline in the email).

You don't have much control over the format, but check out the docs for [sp_send_dbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for details. e.g. look at `@query_result_width` and `@query_result_separator`. You can set the filename as something.csv and then it'll usually be automatically opened as Excel.

As long as you don't have newlines, very long lines, or unescaped breaking characters (such as commas) in your data then it'll probably look *ok*.

If you want to transform the data further you're best off doing it in the query, or if it's more complex then you could embed the query within Excel or use a proper reporting package like SSRS or many others.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply sir but because of office restrictions i cannot use SSRS. Therefore, I kindly request you to please provide me other solution.